# Android mp3 sound increase

Tags: android

I have done the app like talking tom to repeat the voice again. But the playback sound is very low.So please tell me how to increase the mp3 sound manually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AudioManager to increase the volume to 100 percent.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVol = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVol, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

You will need the Audio Settings permission.

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

I will say, though, that you probably *don't* want to do this. The user knows what volume they want the playback to be at, and they will set it where they want it to be.

Comment: But when i use this code it will increase the default device sound.but my query is about Is there any way to increase the mp3 sound like increasing sampling value in android.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. There is the STREAM_MUSIC stream, which controls the volume of audio files played as music. If the file itself is encoded too low, you will need to re-encode it.